# Sorting Data By SQL Statement

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below is a table which stores the value of personal_id and date:

```
  Person_ID    Effective_Date     End Effective_Date
  1)6335         24/02/1999
  2)6335         09/07/1998
  3)6335         26/06/1998
```

and the output table should be like

```
  Person_ID    Effective_Date     End Effective_Date
  1)6335         24/02/1999           31/12/9999
  2)6335         09/07/1998           23/02/1999
  3)6335         26/06/1998           08/07/1998
```

The logic will be very easy if I updated it by using java code. But can it be done by using SQL statement? I need someone to provide me the logic to do it. My current end effective date will always be a day before the next effective date. Lets say my effective date for row number 2 is 09/07/1988 then my end effective date for row number 1 should be a day before it (08/07/1988). While my end effective date for max effective date will always be 31/12/9999.

Comment: what is ur logic for end efeectiveDate?

Comment: Can you please us what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: Hi i just edit my question please have a look 1st. Sorry for didn't make the question clear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you out. Run the query and check the results.

```
DECLARE @tbl table (ID int, D1 DATETIME, D2 DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tbl
select 1,'2/28/2013','2/28/2013'
union all
select 2,'3/2/2013','3/2/2013'
union all
select 3,'4/2/2013','4/2/2013'
union all
select 4,'4/6/2013','4/6/2013'
union all
select 5,'5/21/2013','5/21/2013'
union all
select 6,'6/10/2013','6/10/2013'

SELECT * FROM @tbl

UPDATE t1
SET t1.D2= DATEADD(DAY, -1, t2.D2)
FROM @tbl t1
     CROSS JOIN @tbl t2
WHERE t2.D1=(SELECT min(D1)
               FROM @tbl t
               WHERE D1>t1.D1)


SELECT * FROM @tbl

UPDATE @tbl
SET D2 = '12/31/9999'
WHERE D2 = (SELECT TOP 1 D2 FROM @tbl ORDER BY D2 DESC)

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

This might not be the most efficient case but **it assumes that initially you same values in both D1 and D2.**

Comment: Hi dude thank for your help as well. Your logic can working well. but i much more prefer Alex's answer. Anyway thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lead` function to look ahead to the next row and get its effective date:

```
select person_id, effective_date,
  lead(effective_date)
    over (partition by person_id order by effective_date) as lead_date
from t42;

 PERSON_ID EFFECTIVE_DATE LEAD_DATE
---------- -------------- ---------
      6335 26-JUN-98      09-JUL-98 
      6335 09-JUL-98      24-FEB-99 
      6335 24-FEB-99
```

You can then use that to perform the update. The `merge` command makes this quite easy:

```
merge into t42
using (
  select person_id, effective_date,
    lead(effective_date)
      over (partition by person_id order by effective_date) as lead_date
  from t42
) t
on (t42.person_id = t.person_id and t42.effective_date = t.effective_date)
when matched then
update set t42.end_effective_date =
  case
    when t.lead_date is null then date '9999-12-31'
    else t.lead_date - 1
  end;

3 rows merged.

select * from t42;

 PERSON_ID EFFECTIVE_DATE END_EFFECTIVE_DATE
---------- -------------- ------------------
      6335 26-JUN-98      08-JUL-98          
      6335 09-JUL-98      23-FEB-99          
      6335 24-FEB-99      31-DEC-99
```

The `using` clause has the snippet from above getting the date from the previous row. The `on` clause matches this against your original table, and for the matched row updates the end effective date to the day before the lead effective date, or if there is no lead value (for the most recent, 'current' row) uses the fixed date from 1999.

Your question referred to an update, but if you just want the end date as a calculated column in your result set it's much simpler:

```
select person_id, effective_date,
  case when lead_date is null then date '9999-12-31'
    else lead_date - 1 end as end_effective_date
from (
  select person_id, effective_date,
    lead(effective_date)
      over (partition by person_id order by effective_date) as lead_date
  from t42
);

 PERSON_ID EFFECTIVE_DATE END_EFFECTIVE_DATE
---------- -------------- ------------------
      6335 26-JUN-98      08-JUL-98          
      6335 09-JUL-98      23-FEB-99          
      6335 24-FEB-99      31-DEC-99
```

Comment: Hi dude, very impressive by the SQL statement u wrote just now. it really help me a lot and the instruction is clear. You provide me a clear direction to do it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE personal_id SET [End Effective_Date] = To_date('31/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
 WHERE Person_ID = 6335 AND Effective_Date = To_date('24/02/1999', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: Hi dude, i just edit my question just now. please have a look 1st. (^.^) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yet you must have the couples of Effective_date with the next effective_date

```
SELECT P1.Effective_Date, P2.Effective_Date 
FROM personal_id P1, personal_id P2 where P1.Effective_Date < P2.Effective_Date 
GROUP BY P1.Effective_Date
HAVING P2.Effective_Date = MIN(P2.Effective_Date)
```

I think that it must be better with a join

after that:
you make un update on the End Effective date.

Comment: Hi katria, how about if the end effective is not provide and it must be control by the logic in SQL which is always a day before the next effective date?